# Can't solve Coulomb Force differential equation in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I'm trying to solve a problem: I have to find the trajectory of an electron in a graphene lattice using Mathematica. I've tried to solve the Coulomb Force equation with NDSolve and to plot the result for each direction, but i obtain a white plot. Could someone help me please? Thank you in advance. Here's the code for the x direction:

```
coordx = {0.6327, 1.88058, 3.03927, 4.28716, 5.44584, 6.69373, 
   7.85241, 9.10029, 1.9728, 3.22069, 4.37937, 5.62726, 6.78594, 
   8.03382, 9.19251, 10.4404, 3.3129, 4.56079, 5.71947, 6.96736, 
   8.12604, 9.37393, 10.53261, 11.7805, 4.653, 5.90089, 7.05956, 
   8.30746, 9.46614, 10.71403, 11.87271, 13.1206};
me = 9.01*10^-31;
pi = 3.14159;
epsilon0 = 8.854*10^-12;
q = -1.6*10^-19;
Q = 1.6*10^-19;
step = 0.01;
Forzax[p_, r_] := 
 Sum[(Q*q)/(4 pi*epsilon0*Norm[r - p[[i]]]^2), {i, Length[p]}]
Forzax[coordx, {x[t]}];
NDSolve[{x''[t] == Forzax[coordx, {x[t]}]/me , x[0] == 0, 
  x'[0] == 0}, {x[t]}, {t, 0, 1500}]
Show[ParametricPlot[Evaluate[{x[t]} /. %], {t, 0, 1500}, 
  PlotRange -> All]]
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you're trying to plot, but these few modifications seem to plot your function.

```
sol = NDSolve[{x''[t] == Forzax[coordx, {x[t]}]/me,
    x[0] == 0, x'[0] == 0}, {x}, {t, 0, 1500}];
f = sol[[1, 1, 2]];
Plot[f[t], {t, 0, 1500}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: I'm trying to plot the trajectory of an electron in graphene lattice. So i have my equations: mx''=Fcx; my''=Fcy, mz''=Fcz. I have to solve these equations and to plot the trajectory of the electron in a 3D x,y,z graph. Actually I'm just trying to plot the single differential equation result(first step). How can i solve my problem? I' m new in Mathematica. Thank you for yor advice.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, your code is running fine but the plot is empty because you're calling `ParametricPlot` with just one function. From the documentation, this is how you call `ParametricPlot`:

```
ParametricPlot[{fx[t], fy[t]}, {t, tmin, tmax}]
```

Since you're still solving the 1D problem and only have `x[t]`, `ParametricPlot` cannot draw anything; it's missing the `y` coordinate of the trajectory. Once you do a 2D calculation, `ParamatricPlot` should be able to give you to figure you want. If you want to do a 3D calculation, you should use `ParamatricPlot3D`.

A question though: how do you intend to to a 3D calculation of an electron in graphene? The motion of the electron in the 3rd dimension will not follow Newtonian mechanics at all because it is confined so much in that direction. In fact, I'd be kind of cautious about using Newton's 2nd law in graphene no matter what, since electrons in graphene behave like massless particles. I leave the interpretation of the results up to you, but the physicist in me cannot resist adding this word of caution.